# change css property with onClick function on React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, onclick

I have this code on css:

```
.coin {
    height: var(--coin-size);
    width: var(--coin-size);
..(blablabla)
}

.coin::before {
..(blablabla)
    animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
..(blablabla)
}
```

And this code on the JS :

```
   <div className="col-sm" id="coinId">
              <div className="coin" onClick={coinSpin}></div>
            </div>
```

What should I put in the `coinSpin` function so that it will decrease the `animation: spin 5s linear infinite` by 0.5 on every click?

I cannot understand how to access this attribute on the CSS..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-line styling & trigger that styles when the user clicks, or you have an option to use classNames package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing simple stuff in the CSS via state you could add a class to the element you want to modify which will contain the different properties and values. So for example...

```css
.coin {
  color: blue;
}

.coin.spin::before {
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite
}
```

The `.coin.spin` syntax is targeting all the `.coin` elements that contain the `.spin` class. So by adding and remove that class you are making your coin...spin.

In your `onSpin` function you'll add the class and then use setTimeout for 5000 miliseconds and then automatically remove the class.